# How can I get the result from function to json value?

Tags: javascript

I'm so new to node.js
I'm trying to make an interval value in node.js
And I can invoke a function when I reach the exact URL,
however, I do not know how to pass the console.log value to JSON value.

this is my code:

```js
// Import packages
const express = require("express");
// App
const app = express();
   

const port = 8000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500);
  }

  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      doSomething();
      loop();
    }, 1000);
  };
  loop();

  res.json({ random: doSomething() });
});
// Starting server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

I'd like to pass the random number in `doSomething function to` res.json` inside.

So, this is what I tried :

```js
// Import packages
const express = require("express");
// App
const app = express();
   

const port = 8000;

let number;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  function doSomething() {
    number = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    return number;
  }

  const loop = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      doSomething();
      loop();
    }, 1000);
  };
  loop();

  res.json({ random: doSomething() });
});
// Starting server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

However, the above code is working only I refresh the page,
I'd like to change it every second without refresh.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't do that with a response. Because response is returned only once per request

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, How can I achieve what I'm trying??

Comment: You can make a request to the server each one secont(from frontend or another app). You can use `setInterval()` which performs a given action in each inteval

Comment: Omg Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to invoke your function from the client and using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` otherwise it only will run it once.

Keep your server code like this:

```
// Import packages
const express = require("express");
// App
const app = express();
   

const port = 8000;

let number;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  function doSomething() {
    number = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    return number;
  }

  res.json({ random: doSomething() });
});
// Starting server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Then, in a js loaded from the client (browser), you could do something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:8000/")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log("err", err))

}, 1000)
```

That said, using `setInterval` may not be the best thing. I would recommend you to create a HTML `<button>` or an `<a>` and set up and event listener to handle the click event. Then, when the user clicks the button, you could invoke a function to execute the fetch operation.

Comment: @kimtech cool!. Check out the recommendation in the updated version of my answer.